# How to translate NextJS routes based on domain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I have a multi domain site in which I want to translate the URL routes based on the domain.

For ex:

- abcd.com/bathroom
- abcd.de/bad
- abcd.fr/salle-de-bains

I have tried adding next rewrite but I have thousands of product pages. So this method wont work for me because this is not translated based on domain.

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/bad", 
        destination: "/bathroom", 
      },
      {
        source: "/account",
        destination: "/accounto",
      },
    ];
  },
```

Is there any other method I can translate the routes based on domain?
I am using NextJS v13.
I want a solution similar to this site..

- https://xtwostore.com/bathroom.html
- https://xtwostore.de/bad.html
- https://xtwostore.fr/salle-de-bains.html

Comment: Looks like a job for the internationalization library (e.g. react-intl or react-i18next). You would still need to maintain a dictionary, though. For that, you may either use your CMS (if you use one and it provides such a feature) or put together a separate micro-service for that purpose.

Comment: But I dont want the any third party to translate the routes, if a user clicks on the link from .com it should go to /bathroom, and if the user clicks on the same link from .de it should go to /bad. I'll only specify the routes

Comment: I never said you should use third party **to translate** the routes. Translations have to be totally under your control (if you don't want to get 'living_room.html' in one case and 'guest_room.html' in another one). However, managing those translations (store, modify and delete them) is better to be done outside of Next.js (for separation of concerns) as business might decide one day that for SEO purposes they need to have "washroom.html" instead of "bathroom.html" and you need to rebuild and redeploy the app for every such case.

Comment: I believe you have to do the whole routing yourself, e.g. using [next.js middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), or custom scripts to create the list of next.js rewrites. I don't know next v13 well though. Next js has built-in [i18n features](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing), but that can't handle translated sub-path.